# Font Awesome only works on mobile browsers

Tags: css, import, gulp, font-awesome

Here's my structure

```
project
  assets
    scripts
    fonts
    styles
      font-awesome
        scss
          font-awesome.scss
        fonts
      app.scss
  bower_components
  node_modules
  public
    css
      app.min.css
    js
    fonts
  bower.json
  gulpfile.js
  package.json
```

I use gulp just to copy font-awesome to public folder.

```
gulp.task('fonts', function() {
    return gulp.src([path.bower.awesome.fonts.src, path.src.fonts])
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.bower.awesome.fonts.public))
});
```

Then I import fonts to app.scss

```
@import 'font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';
```

But it doesn't work on browsers except mobile browsers. What do I do wrong?

here's app.min.css

```
*/@font-face{font-family:FontAwesome;src:url(../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.4.0);src:url(../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.4.0) format("embedded-opentype"),url(../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0) format("woff2"),url(../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.4.0) format("woff"),url(../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.4.0) format("truetype"),url(../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.4.0#fontawesomeregular) format("svg"); 

/* Code code code */

fa-glass:before{content:""}.fa-music:before{content:""}.fa-search:before{content:""}.fa-envelope-o:before{content:""}.fa-heart:before{content:""}.fa-star:before{content:""}.fa-star-o:before{content:""}.fa-user:before{content:""}.fa-film:before{content:""}.fa-th-large:before{content:""}.fa-th:before{content:""}.fa-th-list:before{content:""}.fa-check:before{content:""}.fa-close:before,.fa-remove:before,.fa-times:before{content:""}.fa-search-plus:before{content:""}.fa-search-minus:before{content:""}.fa-power-off:before{content:""}.fa-signal:before{content:""}.fa-cog:before,.fa-gear:before{content:""}.fa-trash-o:before{content:""}.fa-home:before{content:""}.fa-file-o:before{content:""}.fa-clock-o:before{content:""}.fa-road:before{content:""}.fa-download:before{content:""}.fa-arrow-circle-o-down:before{content:""}.fa-arrow-circle-o-up:before{content:""}.fa-inbox:before{content:""}.fa-play-circle-o:before{content:""}.fa-repeat:before,.fa-rotate-right:before{content:""}.fa-refresh:before{content:""}.fa-list-alt:before{content:""}.fa-lock:before{content:""}.fa-flag:before{content:""}.fa-headphones:before{content:""}.fa-volume-off:before{content:""}.fa-volume-down:before{content:""}.fa-volume-up:before{content:""}.fa-qrcode:before{content:""}.fa-barcode:before{content:""}.fa-tag:before{content:""}.fa-tags:before{content:""}.fa-book:before{content:""}.fa-bookmark:before{content:""}.fa-print:before{content:""}.fa-camera:before{content:""}.fa-font:before{content:""}.fa-bold:before{content:""}.fa-italic:before{content:""}.fa-text-height:before{content:""}.fa-text-width:before{content:""}.fa-align-left:before{content:""}.fa-align-center:before{content:""}.fa-align-right:before{content:""}.fa-align-justify:before{content:""}.fa-list:before{content:""}.fa-dedent:before,.fa-outdent:before{content:""}.fa-indent:before{content:""}.fa-video-camera:before{content:""}.fa-image:before,.fa-photo:before,.fa-picture-o:before{content:""}.fa-pencil:before{content:""}.fa-map-marker:before{content:""}.fa-adjust:before{content:""}.fa-tint:before{content:""}.fa-edit:before,.fa-pencil-square-o:before{content:""}.fa-share-square-o:before{content:""}.fa-check-square-o:before{content:""}.fa-arrows:before{content:""}.fa-step-backward:before{content:""}.fa-fast-backward:before{content:""}.fa-backward:before{content:""}.fa-play:before{content:""}.fa-pause:before{content:""}.fa-stop:before{content:""}.fa-forward:before{content:""}.fa-fast-forward:before{content:""}.fa-step-forward:before{content:""}.fa-eject:before{content:""}.fa-chevron-left:before{content:""}.fa-chevron-right:before{content:""}.fa-plus-circle:before{content:""}.fa-minus-circle:before{content:""}.fa-times-circle:before{content:""}.fa-check-circle:before{content:""}.fa-question-circle:before{content:""}.fa-info-circle:before{content:""}.fa-crosshairs:before{content:""}.fa-times-circle-o:before{content:""}.fa-check-circle-o:before{content:""}.fa-ban:before{content:""}.fa-arrow-left:before{content:""}.fa-arrow-right:before{content:""}.fa-arrow-up:before{content:""}.fa-arrow-down:before{content:""}.fa-mail-forward:before,.fa-share:before{content:""}.fa-expand:before{content:""}.fa-compress:before{content:""}.fa-plus:before{content:""}.fa-minus:before{content:""}.fa-asterisk:before{content:""}.fa-exclamation-circle:before{content:""}.fa-gift:before{content:""}.fa-leaf:before{content:""}.fa-fire:before{content:""}.fa-eye:before{content:""}.fa-eye-slash:before{content:""}.fa-exclamation-triangle:before,.fa-warning:before{content:""}.fa-plane:before{content:""}.fa-calendar:before{content:""}.fa-random:before{content:""}.fa-comment:before{content:""}.fa-magnet:before{content:""}.fa-chevron-up:before{content:""}.fa-chevron-down:before{content:""}.fa-retweet:before{content:""}.fa-shopping-cart:before{content:""}.fa-folder:before{content:""}.fa-folder-open:before{content:""}.fa-arrows-v:before{content:""}.fa-arrows-h:before{content:""}.fa-bar-chart-o:before,.fa-bar-chart:before{content:""}.fa-twitter-square:before{content:""}.fa-facebook-square:before{content:""}.fa-camera-retro:before{content:""}.fa-key:before{content:""}.fa-cogs:before,.fa-gears:before{content:""}.fa-comments:before{content:""}.fa-thumbs-o-up:before{content:""}.fa-thumbs-o-down:before{content:""}.fa-star-half:before{content:""}.fa-heart-o:before{content:""}.fa-sign-out:before{content:""}.fa-linkedin-square:before{content:""}.fa-thumb-tack:before{content:""}.fa-external-link:before{content:""}.fa-sign-in:before{content:""}.fa-trophy:before{content:""}.fa-github-square:before{content:""}.fa-upload:before{content:""}.fa-lemon-o:before{content:""}.fa-phone:before{content:""}.fa-square-o:before{content:""}.fa-bookmark-o:before{content:""}.fa-phone-square:before{content:""}.fa-twitter:before{content:""}.fa-facebook-f:before,.fa-facebook:before{content:""}.fa-github:before{content:""}.fa-unlock:before{content:""}.fa-credit-card:before{content:""}.fa-feed:before,.fa-rss:before{content:""}.fa-hdd-o:before{content:""}.fa-bullhorn:before{content:""}.fa-bell:before{content:""}.fa-certificate:before{content:""}.fa-hand-o-right:before{content:""}.fa-hand-o-left:before{content:""}.fa-hand-o-up:before{content:""}.fa-hand-o-down:before{content:""}.fa-arrow-circle-left:before{content:""}.fa-arrow-circle-right:before{content:""}.fa-arrow-circle-up:before{content:""}.fa-arrow-circle-down:before{content:""}.fa-globe:before{content:""}.fa-wrench:before{content:""}.fa-tasks:before{content:""}.fa-filter:before{content:""}.fa-briefcase:before{content:""}.fa-arrows-alt:before{content:""}.fa-group:before,.fa-users:before{content:""}.fa-chain:before,.fa-link:before{content:""}.fa-cloud:before{content:""}.fa-flask:before{content:""}.fa-cut:before,.fa-scissors:before{content:""}.fa-copy:before,.fa-files-o:before{content:""}.fa-paperclip:before{content:""}.fa-floppy-o:before,.fa-save:before{content:""}.fa-square:before{content:""}.fa-bars:before,.fa-navicon:before,.fa-reorder:before{content:""}.fa-list-ul:before{content:""}.fa-list-ol:before{content:""}.fa-strikethrough:before{content:""}.fa-underline:before{content:""}.fa-table:before{content:""}.fa-magic:before{content:""}.fa-truck:before{content:""}.fa-pinterest:before{content:""}.fa-pinterest-square:before{content:""}.fa-google-plus-square:before{content:""}.fa-google-plus:before{content:""}.fa-money:before{content:""}.fa-caret-down:before{content:""}.fa-caret-up:before{content:""}.fa-caret-left:before{content:""}.fa-caret-right:before{content:""}.fa-columns:before{content:""}.fa-sort:before,.fa-unsorted:before{content:""}.fa-sort-desc:before,.fa-sort-down:before{content:""}.fa-sort-asc:before,.fa-sort-up:before{content:""}.fa-envelope:before{content:""}.fa-linkedin:before{content:""}.fa-rotate-left:before,.fa-undo:before{content:""}.fa-gavel:before,.fa-legal:before{content:""}.fa-dashboard:before,.fa-tachometer:before{content:""}.fa-comment-o:before{content:""}.fa-comments-o:before{content:""}.fa-bolt:before,.fa-flash:before{content:""}.fa-sitemap:before{content:""}.fa-umbrella:before{content:""}.fa-clipboard:before,.fa-paste:before{content:""}.fa-lightbulb-o:before{content:""}.fa-exchange:before{content:""}.fa-cloud-download:before{content:""}.fa-cloud-upload:before{content:""}.fa-user-md:before{content:""}.fa-stethoscope:before{content:""}.fa-suitcase:before{content:""}.fa-bell-o:before{content:""}.fa-coffee:before{content:""}.fa-cutlery:before{content:""}.fa-file-text-o:before{content:""}.fa-building-o:before{content:""}.fa-hospital-o:before{content:""}.fa-ambulance:before{content:""}.fa-medkit:before{content:""}.fa-fighter-jet:before{content:""}.fa-beer:before{content:""}.fa-h-square:before{content:""}.fa-plus-square:before{content:""}.fa-angle-double-left:before{content:""}.fa-angle-double-right:before{content:""}.fa-angle-double-up:before{content:""}.fa-angle-double-down:before{content:""}.fa-angle-left:before{content:""}.fa-angle-right:before{content:""}.fa-angle-up:before{content:""}.fa-angle-down:before{content:""}.fa-desktop:before{content:""}.fa-laptop:before{content:""}.fa-tablet:before{content:""}.fa-mobile-phone:before,.fa-mobile:before{content:""}.fa-circle-o:before{content:""}.fa-quote-left:before{content:""}.fa-quote-right:before{content:""}.fa-spinner:before{content:""}.fa-circle:before{content:""}.fa-mail-reply:before,.fa-reply:before{content:""}.fa-github-alt:before{content:""}.fa-folder-o:before{content:""}.fa-folder-open-o:before{content:""}.fa-smile-o:before{content:""}.fa-frown-o:before{content:""}.fa-meh-o:before{content:""}.fa-gamepad:before{content:""}.fa-keyboard-o:before{content:""}.fa-flag-o:before{content:""}.fa-flag-checkered:before{content:""}.fa-terminal:before{content:""}.fa-code:before{content:""}.fa-mail-reply-all:before,.fa-reply-all:before{content:""}.fa-star-half-empty:before,.fa-star-half-full:before,.fa-star-half-o:before{content:""}.fa-location-arrow:before{content:""}.fa-crop:before{content:""}.fa-code-fork:before{content:""}.fa-chain-broken:before,.fa-unlink:before{content:""}.fa-question:before{content:""}.fa-info:before{content:""}.fa-exclamation:before{content:""}.fa-superscript:before{content:""}.fa-subscript:before{content:""}.fa-eraser:before{content:""}.fa-puzzle-piece:before{content:""}.fa-microphone:before{content:""}.fa-microphone-slash:before{content:""}.fa-shield:before{content:""}.fa-calendar-o:before{content:""}.fa-fire-extinguisher:before{content:""}.fa-rocket:before{content:""}.fa-maxcdn:before{content:""}.fa-chevron-circle-left:before{content:""}.fa-chevron-circle-right:before{content:""}.fa-chevron-circle-up:before{content:""}.fa-chevron-circle-down:before{content:""}.fa-html5:before{content:""}.fa-css3:before{content:""}.fa-anchor:before{content:""}.fa-unlock-alt:before{content:""}.fa-bullseye:before{content:""}.fa-ellipsis-h:before{content:""}.fa-ellipsis-v:before{content:""}.fa-rss-square:before{content:""}.fa-play-circle:before{content:""}.fa-ticket:before{content:""}.fa-minus-square:before{content:""}.fa-minus-square-o:before{content:""}.fa-level-up:before{content:""}.fa-level-down:before{content:""}.fa-check-square:before{content:""}.fa-pencil-square:before{content:""}.fa-external-link-square:before{content:""}.fa-share-square:before{content:""}.fa-compass:before{content:""}.fa-caret-square-o-down:before,.fa-toggle-down:before{content:""}.fa-caret-square-o-up:before,.fa-toggle-up:before{content:""}.fa-caret-square-o-right:before,.fa-toggle-right:before{content:""}.fa-eur:before,.fa-euro:before{content:""}.fa-gbp:before{content:""}.fa-dollar:before,.fa-usd:before{content:""}.fa-inr:before,.fa-rupee:before{content:""}.fa-cny:before,.fa-jpy:before,.fa-rmb:before,.fa-yen:before{content:""}.fa-rouble:before,.fa-rub:before,.fa-ruble:before{content:""}.fa-krw:before,.fa-won:before{content:""}.fa-bitcoin:before,.fa-btc:before{content:""}.fa-file:before{content:""}.fa-file-text:before{content:""}.fa-sort-alpha-asc:before{content:""}.fa-sort-alpha-desc:before{content:""}.fa-sort-amount-asc:before{content:""}.fa-sort-amount-desc:before{content:""}.fa-sort-numeric-asc:before{content:""}.fa-sort-numeric-desc:before{content:""}.fa-thumbs-up:before{content:""}
```

and so on

Update: Guys, I forgot to say that It works when I open the site on localhost

Comment: Can you post a link to a webpage where you see your problem, so this can be debugged?

Comment: http://scand.pancakeapps.com/  mobile navigation contains several icons

Comment: I'm debugging in Firefox and the font files seem to be broken. The inspector is complaining that the woff2, woff and ttf files of the FontAwesome font are not specifying their correct size or range, and therefore the browser's sanitizer rejects these files and thus they aren't used for displaying your website. Can you make sure the font files to which you link in your app.min.css are valid?

Comment: I would give it a manual try and download the fonts, upload them via ftp, check the paths and try again. I had a similar problem a couple of months ago.

Answer (score 0):

I tested by adding this line inside your app.min.css: @import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css";

It works. So the fault lies somewhere with the font package on your server.[image]

Comment: Guys, I forgot to say that It works when I open the site on localhost